# How do I send POST requests with HTTP header containing newlines in postman?

Tags: postman

When HTTP header contains newlines LF or CRLF, postman doesn't even send the request. It gives an error:

[image]

How do I send POST requests containing newlines in postman? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1),

> Line breaks, as in multi-line text field values, are represented as CR LF pairs, i.e. `%0D%0A'

Also, try using the x-www-form-urlencoded format to send your request. Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean, HTTP headers, right? Because HTML headers are a whole other thing.

Comment: Again, refer to the link. You can send new lines with %0D%0A

Answer (score 0):

We have the form-data and binary modes for uploading files. If you're uploading a file, you should use the 'form-data' mode, not the raw mode. form-data mode is for sending non-ASCII text or large binary data.